# Use WIX feature element in wxi and wxs with same Id

Tags: java, javafx, deployment, wix

I want to generate a MSI package which contains only one feature.

I have a wxi file which is generated automatically. I cannot change this process.

wxi file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Include>
 <!-- components -->
 <Feature Id="DefaultFeature" Title="Main Feature" Level="1">
    <ComponentRef Id="comp0" />
    <ComponentRef Id="comp1" />
    <ComponentRef Id="comp2" />
    <ComponentRef Id="comp3" />
    <ComponentRef Id="CleanupMainApplicationFolder" />
 </Feature>
</Include>
```

I have a wxs file which I can change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
    <Product ...>
        <!-- components -->
        <?include bundle.wxi ?>
        <UI/>
        <FeatureRef Id="DefaultFeature">
            <ComponentRef Id="comp999" />
        </FeatureRef>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

When I compile the wxs to MSI package Light is stating this error:

> error LGHT0095 : Multiple primary references were found for Feature 'DefaultFeature' in Product '{...}' and Product '{...}'.

How do I change my wxs file to add a component to the feature defined in wxi file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<ComponentGroup>` in your include files instead of `<Feature>`. Then, define your features in one place, the main `.wxs` file with `<Product>` element.

For example, this is how include file might look:

```
<Fragment>
<Component Id="Comp1" Guid="{GUID-GOES-HERE}">
  ...
</Component>
<Component Id="Comp2" Guid="{GUID-GOES-HERE}">
  ...
</Component>
<Component Id="Comp3" Guid="{GUID-GOES-HERE}">
  ...
</Component>

<ComponentGroup Id="CG1">
  <ComponentRef Id="Comp1"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="Comp2"/>
  <ComponentRef Id="Comp3"/>
</ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

And the main product.wxs defines the feature, includes the component group in there and allows including more components:

```
<Feature Id="MainFeature" Title="..." Level="100">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="CG1"/>

  <!-- More components can go here -->
  <Component Id="..">
  </Component>
</Feature>
```

Moreover, you can include wxs files instead of include, too. As long as the main wxs references at least one element from another wxs, the entire contents will be included.

Comment: I cannot change the wxi include file. This include file is generated automatically.

Comment: Hmm, in this case, instead of adding FeatureRef with the same Id, you can specify `Feature="DefaultFeature"` as attribute for those extra components...